# Objective-c and Swift mixed project -Swift.h file report errors

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, project

I use SVN update the project, then my project report errors below:

[image]

My report errors code is here:

```
SWIFT_CLASS_PROPERTY(@property (nonatomic, class, readonly, copy)   NSString * _Nonnull Mob_App_Key;) // error:Expected an Objective-C directive after '@'
+ (NSString * _Nonnull)Mob_App_Key;
SWIFT_CLASS_PROPERTY(@property (nonatomic, class, readonly, copy)   NSString * _Nonnull Mob_App_Secret;)
+ (NSString * _Nonnull)Mob_App_Secret;
```

But you see my defines of `Mob_App_Key` or `Mob_App_Secret`:

```
// 银行
static let 中国工商银行 = "中国工商银行"
static let 中国银行 = "中国银行"
static let 中国建设银行 = "中国建设银行"
static let 中国农业银行 = "中国农业银行"
static let 中国邮政银行 = "中国邮政银行"


/* app key */
// 1.Mob
static let Mob_App_Key = "18asd0easdas159b"
static let Mob_App_Secret = "f8asdsdasd25055eb5efd70c43a854"
// 2.Bugly
static let Bugly_App_Id = "fcasdads3"
static let Bugly_App_Secret = "f93b192d-rrrr-4ssss-b604-68bfc49b8f4e"
```

They are no different with `Bugly_App_Id`, and in the `-Swift.h`, `Bugly_App_Id` did not report error, I don't know where comes the errors.

I have restart `Xcode`, and clean my project, it is not work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out the error why appear:

My project in the `SVN`, deleted the `AppDelegate.h` and `AppDelegate.m` and `main.m`, and replaced with `AppDelegate.swift`, means replace Objective-C's `AppDelegate` to Swift's `AppDelegate`, but in my this macbook, the Objective-C's `AppDelegate` is still keep.

My Objective-C's `AppDelegate` is using `Mob_App_Key` and `Mob_App_Secret`.

So I delete my Objective-C's `AppDelegate`, the issues go away.